# Top level Active directory path?

Tags: active-directory

I need to iterate programatically through all items in a specific OU in an active directory tree (C#). For that I have a configuration that specifies which OU to iterate. This works ok.

However my client now wants to iterate through all items in the AD tree. How could I specify a path which contains all OUs in the AD tree so that my application will iterate through all of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify only domain components. E.g.: `LDAP://DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM`

Read more: [Distinguished Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)